PowerQuery: Applied Steps working only partway throough all steps
I have a PowerQuery that is refusing to load data (and thus also update in PowerBI).
Up until the 24th applied step or so, the data preview loads in PowerQuery. However from this step onwards, I receive the information that the Preview Refresh was stopped and needs to be manually restarted. When I attempt this, the preview loads and loads and loads, but never actually loads the data.
I have tried reducing the amount of applied steps, reinitiating the Query in a Blank Query, deleting the Cache and nothing had solved the issue.
When I load the data to PowerBI, the Update screen hangs on "uploading x MB" from the affected Datasource.
Any hints as to what could be causing these overly long/unending preview/load times?

Share more on the data source(s) being used and the transformation steps being used.
